# ICloneable Exists in Two Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.0

Our dot net core 2.0 project has some classes that implement `ICloneable` (they have a `.Clone()` method that returns an `object`). Now, we are using a package `Microsoft.Azure.Amqp` and when building the project now gives an error:

`Error  CS0433  The type 'ICloneable' exists in both 'Microsoft.Azure.Amqp, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'`

Both have `ICloneable` in the "System" namespace, so how can the compiler know which one to use? Is there a way to say which DLL to use for that reference?

Answer (score 0):

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194495/type-exists-in-2-assemblies/17651003#17651003) has a solution to this problem. I'll summarise it briefly. Go to the reference in your project, and change "Aliases" to a value of your choosing. To use code from this assembly now, you will need to use the `extern` keyword like so at the top of your file: `extern alias aliasname`. Then you can reference code from this assembly like so: `aliasname::System.ICloneable`.