# Extension method IsNullOrWhiteSpace with the same namespace is placed in two assemblies

Tags: asp.net, .net, webgrease, ajaxmin

I have ASP.Net MVC project. The project contains WebGrease, packages.config:

```
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Recently because of (https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax/) I added AjaxMin into my packages.config:

```
<package id="AjaxMin" version="5.14.5506.26202" targetFramework="net461" />
```

In my code, I am using IsNullOrWhiteSpace() extension method. The method actually exists in these two libraries:

[image]

Visual Studio cannot decided which one has to be used.

I cannot remove the reference to WebGrease, because if I do so, I have the following exception:

[image]

How can I solve the conflict?

Thank you

Comment: maybe this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194495/type-exists-in-2-assemblies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string.IsNullOrWhitespace() directly.

Comment: That's the correct way. Exactly this was done. Thank you