# The type 'PgpPublicKey' exists in both 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.9.0.0...' and thirdparty dll

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, bouncycastle

Today I need to do some Open PGP encryption/decryption in My web application so I using nuget to add BouncyCastle to my solution, and add some sample code from stackoverflow (SOF) to test encrypt a file.

And the error appear:

> Error CS0433  The type 'PgpPublicKey' exists in both 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e99375e54769942' and 'iTextV***, Version=5.6.140.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

So How to fix that?

After searching in SOF, I found some solution, but cannot fix it yet:

1. Change all dll to [reference the same version](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/45662310/the-type--type--exists-in-both--assembly1--and--netstandard-2-0-assembly-) 1.9.0.0 of BouncyCastle.Crypto. But unluckily, we use 2 third-party dll iTextV***.dll and itext.v***.dll of same company, but we don't have code for them to change reference and rebuild dll.
2. [One post in SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194495/type-exists-in-2-assemblies) told about asembly "Aliases", but we use Web application and have no project reference dll like that to change alias. I tried adding this in web.config but not working, too:

> ```
> <dependentAssembly>
>   <assemblyIdentity name="BouncyCastle.Crypto" publicKeyToken="0e99375e54769942" culture="neutral"/>
>   <bindingRedirect newVersion="1.9.0.0"/>
> ```
>
> </ dependentAssembly>

[image]
After

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extreme thinking or Whatever we could call, I found some possible solution (not best, but acceptable IMO (IN MY OPINION)) in case you couldn't fix it by other solutions found in the internet:

1. Create another c# application project on my own call **B**, reference to `BouncyCastle` library so that no conflict could happen. Then write functions I want and then build project **B** to dll and add that **B** dll to **A** - my main project/ web application as an independence third-party library. So **A** only call functions in **B**, no need to call `BouncyCastle`, no more version conflict.
2. As `BouncyCastle` is open-source project, We could go to [their site](https://www.bouncycastle.org/), download code and then manually add (copy/ paste) necessary classes **Cs** to our main project/ web application **A**, so that all **Cs** become classes in our project. We use **Cs** instead of `using Org.BouncyCastle.*`. No more version conflict. P/S credit to `BouncyCastle` team.