# How to load assembly correctly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I develop a system with plugins, which loads assemblies at runtime. I have a common interface library, which i share between server and its plugins. But, when i perform LoadFrom for plugin folder and try to find all types, which implement common interface `IServerModule` i get runtime exception:

> The type 'ServerCore.IServerModule' exists in both 'ServerCore.dll'
>   and 'ServerCore.dll'

I load plugins like this:

```
foreach (var dll in dlls)
{
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dll);
            var modules = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(
                type => (typeof (IServerModule)).IsAssignableFrom(type)
                && !type.IsAbstract &&
                !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
                .Select(type => (IServerModule)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
            result.AddRange(modules);
}
```

How can i deal with this trouble?

I'll be gratefull for any help

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057853/the-type-type-exists-in-both-dlls

Comment: @Halvard Yes, i do. But i don't have different versions, i have trouble with loadfrom, that loads me similar assembly twice

Comment: Does it load **the same** assembly twice or does it load **a similar** assembly twice?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2007/03/06/assembly-load-contexts-subtleties/)

Comment: @Halvard forgot to mention, it loads similar assembly twice from different place: first it loads it when starts server, and the second cope is located in plugin folder and autoloaded via LoadFrom

Comment: @SriramSakthivel hmm, took a look at paper you provided. Well, i got the idea, but still don't know how to deal with it.. Can you give me advice, please?

Comment: I need more insight of what you're doing to solve this issue, btw I think I used `Assembly.Load(Byte[])` to avoid such issues. If you can provide a sample complete application demonstrating the problem I'd help, otherwise it is hard to guess. Try using `Assembly.Load`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my solution is ugly, but works and i'll go forward for MEF in future (maybe). For now, i added such thing:

```
if(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dll)==Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name)
    continue;
```

Thanks everybody for awesome replies

EDIT: I came up to more elegant solution, here it is:

```
var frameworkAssemblies =
                from file in new DirectoryInfo(frameworkDirectory).GetFiles()
                where (file.Extension.ToLower() == ".dll" || file.Extension.ToLower() == ".exe")
                && !AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.GetName().Name).Contains(file.GetFileNameWithoutExtension())
                select Assembly.LoadFrom(file.FullName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspect the problem DLL and its dependencies.  Chances are good that it is pulling in `ServerCore.dll` from a different version of .NET than your main application.

I recommend you use [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to do plugins.

Comment: Nope... All my projects are build with .Net 4.5. I use Simplee Injector after i get instances of plugins. What also can MEF provide me? I always though that MEF is kind of IoC-container, am i right?

Comment: MEF is specifically for plugins - it does the loading of assemblies and discovery of interface implementations with support for using attributes to configure the plugins.  It is worth reading the front page at least.  For your specific issue, use ndepend or ILSpy or .NET Reflector to examine your DLL and application and verify the ServiceCore.dll that is being pulled in for each.  The error is because the dll is being loaded 2x from different locations.

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy common misconception. MEF is NOT IOC. IOC is NOT a plug in tool. For example you should look at the `Lazy<T, TMetadata>` class that comes with MEF.